# Keep QDialog on top of everything, even fullscreen applications?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, popup, pyside, always-on-top

On a project I work on, using Python3 + PySide, I try to print a popup-message as some sort of notification.

This popup needs to be **on top of everything**, this includes fullscreen applications like games or browsers. And that's the point that does not work. It works fine for all windows on my Desktop, normal windows, maximized, but as soon as there is a fullscreen application or a borderless window ("pseudo fullscreen") the popup is created, but "behind" the fullscreen app.

I already use `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)` but this flag does get ignored by other fullscreen apps.

How do I fix this? Also without giving focus to the popup.
It is just there to present information, and it is not good when your window looses focus while playing a game.

My code can be found here: https://github.com/GosuSan/PyECM

**additional Info:**
- my project aims to be cross-platform, so I need a platform-independend solution
- I am running linux, without having a windows machine atm, 
so I can't test stuff there.

If you need any more info, let me know!

**Edit:**
It seems that `PySide.QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.showMessage` does what I want, it works on fullscreen as well as on borderless-windows. So I will try to either find out how those messages are displayed on top, or just use them, not sure for now.

Comment: The problem I see is that any sane WM should prevent notifications on top of fullscreen windows. At least on Windows and Mac you've got "notification" APIs that do the right thing™, which does not include getting popups on top of fullscreen applications...

Comment: @peppe: that might be the case, but isn't there always a way to ship around such restrictions? If it at least would work in borderless window Mode. Are trayicons not on top, even on fullscreen? Maybe i'll try something with them. I liked the ability to customize the Popup however I want, but if Tray would be the answer I'd go with it. Will Report back.